# Prove that any tree contains a matching of size |InternalNodes|/2

Tags: matching

How can i prove that any tree contains a matching of size |InternalNodes|/2?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What are *internal nodes*? Nodes whose degree is larger than 1?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: internal node is a node that is not a leaf. 
I don't event know where to start. You suggest to prove it by induction?

Comment: Hint : prove by induction that there exists a matching where all internal nodes are covered.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove the following stronger claim by induction:

> Given a rooted tree containing more than one vertex, there is a matching which covers all non-leaf nodes.

The proof is quite simple – we match the root to an arbitrary child, remove the edge, and recurse on the remaining rooted trees. Each remaining tree in which the root is a non-leaf in the original tree will contain more than one vertex, and so the induction hypothesis applies.

I'll let you come up with the details.